# Скрытие блока при открытии другого.

Tags: jquery, html

Суть такова - есть 4 ссылки и 4 скрытых diva, условно:

<a href="#" id="link1">Текст</a>
<a href="#" id="link2">Текст2</a>
<a href="#" id="link3">Текст3</a>
<a href="#" id="link4">Текст4</a>

<div id="div1" class="bar"></div>
<div id="div2" class="bar"></div>
<div id="div3" class="bar"></div>
<div id="div4" class="bar"></div>

В классе прописано display:none;
Как сделать так, чтобы при нажатии на ссылку появлялся соответствующий div, но остальные оставались скрытыми, а при нажатии на другую ссылку, другой div открывался, а предыдущий скрывался ? 
Уже несколько дней пытаюсь сделать, ничего не получается.

Comment: [JQuery UI accordion](http://jqueryui.com/accordion/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

а вот как вы описали, так и делать:

```
$('a').click(function(){$('.bar').eq($(this).index()).show().siblings('.bar').hide()})
```

Comment: единственное, что сопоставлять ссылки с блоками лучше каким-нибудь более надёжным способом, например, id блока писать в href ссылки

Comment: не работает, при открытии страницы появляются все блоки, затем все исчезают и остается только первый. На нажатия на другие ссылки не реагирует

Comment: естественно не работает. Вам только общий принцип предложен.

Показывайте на jsfiddle свой образец кода.

Comment: В общем сделал по этому примеру, все работает, но 1 вопрос, как сделать, чтобы по повторному клику блок обратно скрывался ?

http://jsfiddle.net/winns/9AUuk/

Comment: вам бы разобраться, как это всё работает, а не гуглить готовые решения. Ведь на самом деле всё предельно просто: http://jsfiddle.net/9AUuk/2/

Comment: Спасибо за помощь. Чайник я пока еще.

Comment: так чайником можно остаться, а можно разбираться. Все мы много чего не знаем, всем нужно учиться. Пойдите на api.jquery.com и почитайте о каждом методе из предложенного вам решения, и картина сразу станет ясна.